# definition path to shipping model when create custom shipping method

Tags: module, magento-1, shipping, configuration

Have problem with creating custom shipping method. When new module for shipping method is active then checkout process stop after insert shipping details. No shipping methods shows up either checkout proccess stopped. I think my problem is in definition path to shipping model in my config.xml. Please see my config.xml below. Actually path to model is \app\code\local\Devpassion\Osobno\Model\Carrier\Osobno.php.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Devpassion_Osobno>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Devpassion_Osobno>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <devpassionosobno>
            <class>Devpassion_Osobno_Model</class>
        </devpassionosobno>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <devpassionosobno_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Devpassion_Osobno</module>
            </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
        </devpassionosobno_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
<default>
    <carriers>
        <devpassionosobno>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>Devpassion_Osobno/carrier_osobno</model>
                <name>Devpass Osobno</name>
                <title>Osobno preuzimanje</title>
        </devpassionosobno>
    </carriers>
</default>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out and this is definition of path that works for me. Home someone find this answer useful:

```
 <default>
  <carriers>
   <osobnopr>
       <active>1</active>
       <model>ship/carrier_osobnopr</model>
       <title>Carrier Title</title>
       <name>Method Name</name>
       <price>5.00</price>
   </osobnopr>
 </carriers>
```

I that definition "osobnopr" is name of shipping model. And full path to that model is 
\app\code\local\Devpassion\Ship\Model\Carrier\Osobnopr.php

Comment: If this is the solution please flag it as such. Keping the unanswered questions count down. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the carrier definition should look like this

```
<default>
    <carriers>
        <devpassionosobno>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>devpassionosobno/carrier_osobno</model>
                <name>Devpass Osobno</name>
                <title>Osobno preuzimanje</title>
        </devpassionosobno>
    </carriers>
</default>
```

Also make sure that the model `devpassionosobno/carrier_osobno` (Devpassion_Osobno_Model_Carrier_Osobno) exists and is a valid shipping carrier. I mean check if it extends `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract` or a child of this class and it should implement `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface`. Turn on your error logging and you should be able to see the errors in `var/log`.

Comment: thanks for advice,but still same. This is my error log report: 2013-05-31T19:45:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Devpassion/Osobno/Model/Carrier/Osobno.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/devpass/public_html/testmagento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-05-31T19:45:56+00:00

Comment: this is really strange. Did you clear the cache after modifiyng config.xml? if you did, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: actually i have disabled cache.